# how to add a div inside wp_page_menu

Tags: php, menus

Right now I'm using the `<?php wp_page_menu('menu_class=nav'); ?>` function, which gives this result:

```
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5"></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-7"></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9"></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-11"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Obviously, in every `li` tag there is an `a` tag; so my goal is to add a `div` tag inside the `li` tag and under the `a` tag. How can I do that? I know that I have to create a function in `functions.php`, but I don't know which one. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is light on detail but I'd lean toward a custom Walker:

```
class My_Page_Walker extends Walker_Page {
  function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= '<span>After the Anchor</span></li>';
  }
}

$args = array(
  'walker' => new My_Page_Walker
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

That should insert content just before the closing `</li>` with is what I think you want.